# different single.php for different page templates

Tags: pages, templates, single

I have 4 page templates with same query.

Is it possible to write conditional statement?

1. If I go to single post view (`single.php`) from page template 1
   (`page-main.php`) display something (for example show div),
2. else if I go to single page view (`single.php`) from page template 2
   (`page-second.php`) display something,
3. else etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of the use-case you're going for here? It's a bit difficult to follow. What are the four different page templates, and what is unique about what needs to appear in `single.php` based on each custom page template?

Comment: It appears to me that you need to know what was the visitor coming from before landing on a specific page. You could use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for that, but it's not 100% reliable as some browsers do not send the required header (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php ). Or you could, on the link leading to the template, add a query var that you can then use to identify the origin. For example: `?origin=page-second` and on the page $_GET['origin'] == 'page-second' ...

Comment: @pixeline : could you post that as an "answer" in the answer box below and provide some sample code?